# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden- Upon closing the pop up window ( IE Only)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, telerik, http-status-code-403

I am working on a webApplication that uses telerik. One of the telerik popups up upon closing (by clicking X on top right) gives HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.
[image]

**This happens only on IE. works fine on chrome and firefox**.

My web config have below tags that are required to eliminate this error

```
    runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"

     <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
    <files>
     <clear/>
        <add value="Default.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I see this broken page with HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error." Believe me, nobody else over the internet can see that, so please edit your question to include a screenshot.

Comment: Agreed :) Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple projects in your solution then select one of project and set option 'set up as startup project' then compile and rebuild your project.

Also try to add code below in your web.config file.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, If I include this, I don't see the 403 error but it takes me to to parent directory with the listing of all pages with in it. I would like the pop up to close and stay at parent page as it does on chrome.

Comment: @ Newbee, You can try to refer link below may help you to solve your issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage